# how can can.component returning value to user?

Tags: canjs, canjs-component

Problem: I am building a component where i just need output json object. How can i expose that output so that code can just call component and retrieve that value? (eg. like a getter value)

For e.g. can.component of tree combo as defined over here (http://canjs.com/docs/can.Component.html) allows to select  the values. How can i retrieve back those selected values from can component to use it further in my code ? Like some method which would return me all the values selected which i can reuse it later to pass to some function doing some other computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/bitovi/canjs/issues/1209, there are are several ways to accomplish this. Mainly you have three ways:

- Pass an can.map to the child component, then the sub-component would update this object
- Use DOM events (See 3.2.1 in link above)
- Using can-event as a callback (See 3.2.3)